# sapui5 how to download xstring data into pdf

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to download the xstring data. Here I'm able to download as pdf, but I'm not able to open document. I'm getting an error by saying:

> Failed to load PDF Document

Below is my code that I'm trying:

```javascript
    var data = "%PDF-1.6
%����
405 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 1675/Length 2567/N 200/Type/ObjStm>>stream
hބY]o9�+��^���^�FB�F3b!�[��;��E

aw��{�.;�����kW���ˉƚd�:�
E2�PM��-F��&�-Ɲ� o|���  ��"~%
~e1B�Ā_������#��3�|1ș�M��+�T�US]�2S�5�l����";

        sap.ui.core.util.File.save(data, "filename.pdf", "pdf", "application/pdf");
```

Can you please let me know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: That is not JS, and something is up with your "code"

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/08/14/how-to-upload-and-download-files-using-sap-nw-gateway/ Then do `window.open("/sap/opu/odata/srv/MyEntity('098213')/$value");`

Comment: Thank you Marc.. It is working..